# file permission in zip/7z/rar?

Tags: windows, linux, compression, zip, 7-zip

I want to package my application for linux, I use zip/tar.gz/7z/rar to do the compress in Windows.

Because I do the compress in Windows, so when I extract the package in Linux, the file permission is reset.

The problem is Only the tar.gz can let me extract runable files, other format (zip/7z/rar) not (the file permission is reset to 644).

So my question is how to compress my files using zip/7z/rar while reset the permission to 755.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, zip and rar do not store permissions, I guess 7z also doesn't do it on Windows.

So you can't actually "set" the permisisons while compressing in these formats. I'd suggest using a `tar` based archive for linux targets. If you absolutely need zip or rar, consider using a script that calls `chmod` after unpacking.

Comment: `rar` does support unix permissions, I just tested it out with `rar` command on Archlinux.

Answer (score 4):

Zip does support *nix permissions, but there is no tool under Windows that lets you set them arbitrarily. It is possible to [write a Python script](https://superuser.com/questions/213774/is-there-an-archive-tool-that-runs-on-windows-that-i-can-set-the-execute-attri/213782#213782) that can set them though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use docker to zip files including permissions on windows

```
docker run -it --rm  -v  c:/Users/john/some/where:/data alpine
# within container do
apk add zip && cd /data &&  zip -r archive.zip dir-to-be-zipped
```