# Is there an archive tool (that runs on Windows) that I can set the "execute attribute" in an archive file or zip file?

Tags: zip, archiving, file-attributes

I have a small set of files I develop on Windows but need to extract and run on Linux.  One of those files is a script, StartApp.sh.  I'm packaging the files as a zip archive, passing it to my admin, and asking him to manually set the execute attribute on StartApp.sh before running it.

Is there an archive tool (that runs on Windows) that I can set the "execute attribute" in the archive or zip file itself?  (So when it is extracted on Linux the script will execute without manual steps.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such tool, unless you use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on Windows, a Linux-like environment for Windows.

Your other options are:

- Create an unpack script for your zip that will set the execute permission
- Use a version management system to transfer files, rather than zip

Comment: After a long hiatus I've revisited this issue.  We're using TFS for our source code management, and 'TFS Everywhere' has a method of automatically setting the execute attribute (tracked in a separate meta file per directory).  This answer came closest to the solution I used.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to do a little bit of work, it is possible to write a Python script to do this, using [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html). The trick is to frob the `ZipInfo.external_attr` member for the file in question before using `ZipFile.writestr()` to add it to the archive. See the source of `ZipFile.write()` for the exact manipulation you need to perform.

```
    zinfo.external_attr = (st[0] & 0xFFFF) << 16L      # Unix attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't count on finding an archive utility that lets you do that natively (if the native filesystem doesn't do it, getting an app to do it is unlikely)...my fallback and punt answer for most things windows/linux crossover is cygwin

Answer (score 0):

Use my windows command line utility [zip_exec.zip](http://www.galaxy-forces.com/zip_exec.zip) to set the executable flag for unix and mac (tested on files created with Windows explorer and 7zip). The cpp [source](https://sourceforge.net/p/galaxyv2/code/HEAD/tree/other/zip_exec/) is also available.